# Jquery create element without closing tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In my use case, I need to build some piece of HTML dynamically using jquery.

I start with this function:

```
function createSection(divName) {
    $("#"+ divName).append("<section id='team' class='pb-5'>\
        <div class='container'>");    
}
```

Then I proceed with this function:

```
function createRow(divName) {
     $("#"+ divName).append("<div class='row'>");
}
```

Then I add some other elements before I want to close the row en the section like this:

```
    function closeRow(divName) {
    $("#"+ divName).append("</div>");
}   

function closeSection(divName) {
    $("#"+ divName).append("</div></section>");
}
```

However, Jquery seems to add the closing tags itself. Which messes up my code.

I get this html:

```
<section id="team" class="pb-5">
        <div class="container">
        </div>   </section>
```

After my first function `createSection` is executed.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: please share a demo

Comment: it will automatically generate a closing tag, so it's better to create the HTML string(appending) and insert at last.

Comment: I know it automatically generates the closing tag but how to avoid that?

Comment: is there a reason you can't combine it all into one function?

Comment: Yes because I do not now how many rows I get and between my createRow and Close row I do need to create some more element where I also do not know how many elements that will be.

Comment: Maybe put one complete "section" into an [html template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) and clone it each time you want to add a new section.

Comment: I get my data from a database. Let's say I get some car-types (I do not know how many) and I want max 3 cars in a row. I need to be as flexible as possible as I need to have te possiblily to add different data an different style to each car element

Comment: @hacking_mike :  there is a better way to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements don't have tags. They are whole objects in their own right.

Tags are used to create elements in HTML.

jQuery allows you to use HTML syntax to create elements, but this is just an abstraction. jQuery does not keep a string of HTML in memory and allow you to modify it. It is dealing with **whole elements**.

If you want to work with a string of HTML, then you need to deal with a string and not jQuery.

It's better to work with elements though. Create the div with `$()` and not `append()`. Add children to it. Append it to the parent element.

```
function createRow(divName) {
     var row = $("<div />");
     row.addClass("row");
     $("#"+ divName).append(div);
     return row;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I will try that. Thanks